# Mysql group by doesnt work

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have this simple query, just need to group messages by ticket number

```
SELECT 
    message.id,
    message.ticket,
    message.id_user,
    message.body,
    message.date_add,
    (SELECT name FROM users WHERE id=message.id_user) AS username 
FROM tbl_messages message
WHERE message.id_user=SOME_VALUE 
GROUP BY message.ticket
```

The result is a mysql error "#1055 - Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'db.message.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by"

Comment: What does the output data look like and what are you expecting it to look like?

Comment: The result is a mysql error "#1055 - Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'db.message.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

`SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));`

this query after that execute your query